# getting sub JSON values in an easy way in android

Tags: android, json

```
[{"a":

{"b":"c",
"d":"e",
"f":"g"}

{"a2":

{"b":"c2",
"d":"e2",
"f":"g2"}]
```

This is the JSON data I 'have to' use. Is there any easy way for me to reach, let's say the b values without having to go through a and a2?

Comment: make sure you have posted a valid json

Comment: You are saying that this is not valid? Where is the mistake?

Comment: you can confirm @ jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

You should create a class for that:

```
public class MyObject {
    private A a;
    private A a2;

    // a and a2 getters here to check if it parses successfully
}
```

Class A

```
public class A {
    private String b;
    private String d;
    private String f;

    // getters
}
```

And somewhere where you want to parse:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyObject >>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<MyObject> list = gson.fromJson(yourJsonStringHere, listType);
```